# How to cancel Ado.Net async calls?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a function to query database

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<T>)> RunQuery<T>(string sql)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // ... yield return the result from the reader
```

Some queries take a long time to run and I need to enable it to be cancelable (so it will release the database locks, etc). How to implement it?

Comment: Use the `ExecuteReaderAsync` overload which takes a `CancellationToken`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on the question, use the overload that takes a `CancellationToken`, as you can then trigger cancellation of the request via the `CancellationTokenSource` used to generate the token.

Simulating a long running task by dropping the following code into a Windows Forms app, shows this at work:

```
CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
bool _started = false;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_started)
    {
        _started = true;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(_cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Clicking the button on the form once triggers the request to the database and a second time requests that it be cancelled. This does cause an exception to be thrown which then needs to be handled appropriately:

[image: Exception being thrown by the database request being cancelled]

Comment: Don't use private flags to control it. The problem is that if you decide to handle the sql cancelled exception and set _started back to false. Then it won't actually set that private variable. It has to restore the previous state in the continuation. So you will be setting some cached version of _started, the actual _started will still be true. Next time in it will cancel the task again (you were expecting it to run the sql), and you get a task cancelled exception over and over again.